# Sharding Mongo Surprised to discover

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I am trying to run a sharding in mongo. I ran this commands:

```
mongod --rest --shardsvr --port 10000 --dbpath data/localhost10000 --logpath data/localhost10000/log


mongod --rest --port 10002 --dbpath data/localhost10002 --logpath data/localhost10002/log

mongos --port 10003 --configdb localhost:10002 > run_routing_service_log



mongo localhost:10003

use admin
db.runCommand({addshard:"localhost:10000", name:"shard10000"});
db.runCommand({addshard:"localhost:10001", name:"shard10001"});


use test_sharding
sh.enableSharding("test_sharding")
db.people.ensureIndex({"zip": 1})
db.people.insert({"name": "a1", "password": "a1", .... )

sh.status()
```

I am obtain this error:

Surprised to discover that localhost:10002 does not believe it is a config server

Answer (score 0):

Add --configsvr argument in the second mongod command as below.

`mongod --rest --port 10002 --dbpath data/localhost10002 --logpath data/localhost10002/log`

This should start the configserver on port #10002. However, you might face another issue related to quorum as 3 config-servers are recommended by mongodb official documentation that can be started as the above command on different ports.

Also, I don't see that you have initialized the mongodb shard. That might also create an issue in recognizing correct shard configurations. Following link might be helpful.

http://www.mongodbspain.com/en/2015/01/26/how-to-set-up-a-mongodb-sharded-cluster/